# Is there a way to programmatically remove/update a pdf in iBooks?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, ibooks

Not very hopeful here, but I have to ask... If the user has downloaded a pdf via my iPad app and opted to open it in iBooks (via a handy button in the app), is there a way I can programmatically remove or update the pdf in iBooks?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot access any information from ibook because its in sandbox mode.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is the Edit button at the top right.

Then select the ones you want to delete, and then tap on the delete button.

Comment: Thanks Federico. That's in iBooks itself, right? I was hoping I could do it programmatically from within my app?...

Comment: Yes, the question wasn't clear if you were asking about usability or programmatically. Not sure if you can do that, though. Probably the best would be to delete the file directly, but iBooks renames the pdfs to some apple library naming convention with random numbers and letters.